# [mongoid][factory_girl] How to make factory_girl create in safe mode ? (mongoid safe mode)

Tags: cucumber, mongoid, factory-bot

Is there anyway to make factory_girl create records in mongoid safe mode??
The original code is:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create( :user, email: email )
```

But it failed without exceptions, cause by the duplicated key of compound index (db truncated, but indexes hasn't been removed by mongodb). I have to change the code to :

```
@user = User.safely.create!({
  email: email, 
  password: Digest::MD5.hexdigest('123456')
})
```

So I can see why factory_girl didn't create the User successful.
Is there anyway to make factory_girl create record in safe mode like:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.safely.create( :user, email: email )
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This trick may help. The following test passes:

```
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      it "deletes a user" do
        user.new_record?
        expect { delete :destroy, :id => user.id }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
      end
```

If - user.new_record? - commented, test fails.